# Opencv подсчет объектов на поле

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

У меня есть фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хотел бы получить примерное количество зеленых растений на поле, как это можно сделать? Я пытался благодаря numpy и opencv, но не очень хорошо понимаю, как он работает. Очень нужна ваша помощь!

Comment: Я бы OpenCV скорее даже не трогал-бы, он в таком плане туповат. Можно попробовать постобработкой снизить количество цветов до с 32bpp на 255, заменить в pallete по HSL приближенные к зелёному (с заданной чувствительностью) на ярко красные 255,0,0 и потом посчитать сколько тебя жирных красных точек на фото..

Comment: На выхлопе получиться что-то похожее на вот это https://ibb.co/VwPFg8G

Comment: По факту как работает OpenCV - у него есть набор эталонных изображений из которых он создаёт векторы которые могли-бы быть схожи с объектами на изображении. А на твоём фото из чего создавать векторы из маленьких зелёных точек?

Comment: А как после можно получить количество объектов?

Comment: И могли бы оставить пример кода с помощью, которого вы получили фото с точками.